# GridBagLayout align left

Tags: java, swing, alignment, gridbaglayout

This is my code:

```
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
                p.setBackground(Color.green);
                GridBagConstraints c1 = new GridBagConstraints();
                c1.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
                c1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
                int index = 0;
                int i2 = 0;
                for(String[] data : attribute.choices){
                    JCheckBox checkbox = new JCheckBox(data[0]);
                    checkbox.setBackground(Color.red);
                    checkbox.setSelected(false);
                    c1.gridx = index % 2;
                    c1.gridy = index / 2;
                    p.add(checkbox, c1);
                    index++;
                }
                panel.add(p);
```

And this is the result:

[image]
.

I want the checkbox (the red area) alinged to the right. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want the checkbox (the red area) alinged to the right.

By default a panel uses a "center aligned" FlowLayout. You can change the alignment to be `right aligned`.

```
//panel.add(p);
panel.setLayout( new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT) );
panel.add(p);
```

Comment: This won't work. As you can see JPanel p has a green background and has already full width. The checkboxes (green) are the one that are centered.

Comment: @JochemGruter, did you try it?